# Не отображается текст параметра data-description

Tags: html, вконтакте, параметры

```js
< script src = "https://yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"
async = "async" > < /script> <
script src = "https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"
async = "async" > < /script>
```

```html
<p style="float:left;margin-top:18px">Поделиться:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<div style="float:left;margin-left=400px;margin-top:18px" class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,twitter,facebook,gplus" data-description="дескрипшен" data-url="https://rgloss.ru/posti/post1.html" data-title="Преображение Виктории" data-image="https://rgloss.ru/img/t1-1.jpg">
</div>
```

**Не отображается текст параметра data-description**

Здравствуйте, не могу понять почему не отображается текст параметра data-description.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело.
Нужно, чтобы, например в ВК, сверху над ссылкой и картинкой был текст.
И еще вопрос, можно ли там же, рядом с текстом сверху поместить фото? Каким параметром это делается?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше скопируйте код и ставьте сюда.

Comment: @Nikita весь код html?

Comment: Достаточно только того, который у вас на скрине